Java PrinterJob prints blank pages
I tried printing for the fiest time and found these code snippets:
package main;

import java.awt.print.Book;
import java.awt.print.PageFormat;
import java.awt.print.PrinterException;
import java.awt.print.PrinterJob;

import objects.Dokument;

public class Drucker {

    public Drucker() {
        try {
            
            PrinterJob pj = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
            Book pb = new Book();
            PageFormat pf = new PageFormat();
            pf.setOrientation(PageFormat.PORTRAIT);
            
            pb.append(new Dokument(), pf);
            pb.append(new Dokument(), pf);
            
            System.out.println(pb.getNumberOfPages());
            
            pj.setPageable(pb);
            
            if(pj.printDialog()) {
                pj.print();
            }
            
        } catch (PrinterException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
    }
    
}

and the Dokument class:
package objects;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.print.PageFormat;
import java.awt.print.Printable;
import java.awt.print.PrinterException;

public class Dokument implements Printable {

    @Override
    public int print(Graphics g, PageFormat pf, int pi) throws PrinterException {
        
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, 50, 50);
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.drawString("Hello World", 50, 50);
        
        return 0;
    }

}

While it manages to print multiple pages, they are blank.
My guess was that this has something to do with the Graphics but i couldnt find any Graphics tags i could implement to make it work.

Do not return 0, return:

Printable.NO_SUCH_PAGE if pi is not a correct page number,
Printable.PAGE_EXISTS if pi is a correct page number and you rendered something into it.

